# Ionic 6 - localization of Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using Angular 13 and Ionic 6 to add [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). Here is a [simple example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language#maps_map_language-typescript) provided by Google to add the map using TypeScript.

When using Ionic, I am supposed to add the following in the `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ZZZZZ&language=en&region=ca" async defer>
</script>
```

Then, I will use it in the appropriate components throughout the application. As you can see, the language and region have been hardcoded in the script. I am not sure how would I allow the user to dynamically choose the language and region.

The objective is to have [Google's localization example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demos/localization) implemented using Ionic. The languages I am interested in adding are English and French.

I tried to add the script in the html file of the component but that didn't work. I even tried to dynamically remove and insert a script but it seemed too complicated. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Not much of a help for that particular issue, but as of recently you have Capacitor Google Maps plugin from Ionic team: https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-the-capacitor-google-maps-plugin/ so you might find something useful or easier there.

Comment: @MishaMashina, thank you for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of this as it is relatively new. I am hoping to have my question answered as I have implemented all the necessary components required for my application. I wouldn't want to refactor everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loader to add google maps dynamically, like mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#js_api_loader_package

```
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  version: "weekly",
  ...additionalOptions,
});

loader.load().then(() => {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
});
```

and use variable for language and region selection